# Upload file to s3 browser through batch script

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am trying to upload a json file to S3 browser through batch script using command:

```
s3browser-con.exe upload <account_name> <local directory\json file> <s3 bucket name and path>
```

(Referred CLI documentation). However, I get error:

> :AccountManager::CurrentAccount::get::failed - unable to show the Add New Account dialog.

This runs fine when I run the batch script individually, however, when I try to run it through command task in Informatica cloud, it gives me this error.

I suspect this is trying to create new account at runtime, but we can only add two accounts at a time since it is free version. Not sure though as I am new to S3 and batch scripts.

Also, is there any way, we can avoid giving account name, as all users might have different account name for a particular bucket?  Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Note: This is detailed error Unhandled Exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at mg.b(String aty) at mk.a(String[] avx) at mg.Main(String[] args)

Comment: This is detailed error Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at mg.b(String aty)
   at mk.a(String[] avx)
   at mg.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

<account_name> is held in the User Profile of whoever set it up in s3browser-con. So if you are not running Informatica (secure agent) on the same machine under the same user then it's not going to work.

However, why are you using a 3rd party tool to upload files to S3 within Informatica? Why not just use Informatica's built-in capabilities? Unless there is a very specific reason for doing this, your solution appears to be over complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My end goal is to upload json file to azure blob. I am not sure if IICS can read json file directly and publish into azure as it is. I dont want to use hierarchy parser as it will convert the fields into tabular format. Right now, i am trying to upload to s3 through batch, and from s3 to azure through iics mapping Any suggestions for better solution?